# Git Rebase Abort Doesn't Remove ../.git/rebase-apply

Tags: git, git-rebase

I just had the worst rebase experience of master on to my feature branch and now at the end of it I can't seem to remove this directory and I'm stuck in AM/REBASE.  I can't --continue, am --abort, or just --abort to finish up or reverse the rebase.  Why did this happen? and How do you fix it?

```
mtpultz@myPC /c/htdocs/myproj(unify_theme|AM/REBASE)
$ git rebase --continue
Stray c:/htdocs/myproj/.git/rebase-apply directory found.
Use "git am --abort" to remove it.

mtpultz@myPC /c/htdocs/myproj (unify_theme|AM/REBASE)
$ git am --abort
rm: cannot remove directory `c:/htdocs/myproj/.git/rebase-apply': Permission denied
```

Comment: Are you using Windows? It may be caused by Windows permissions and not be related to Git. Usually `.git/rebase-apply` can be removed by hand w/o problems. Also, I suspect that `Stray c:/htdocs/myproj/.git/rebase-apply directory found` may be caused by your Git client not being able to read `rebase-apply` directory contents.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, some process must have been preventing access, but restarting my laptop, and running git am --abort again solved the issue.